# Button in Fragment are not working in android

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, fragment

I have read a lot of posts and questions and answers but I can't resolve my problem. It is not working.

I have an App with the Mainmenu-Activity from the Android Studio. Now I have some Fragments that are set into the container (via replace).

Now I added a button into the Fragment and want that it will do some calculations. But here is the Problem. This Button is not doing anything.

Here my Code:

```
package eu.terratex.terratextoolbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Knastrechner.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Knastrechner#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */
public class Knastrechner extends Fragment  {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private Button btnClick;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment Knastrechner.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Knastrechner newInstance() {
        Knastrechner fragment = new Knastrechner();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        return fragment;
    }
    public Knastrechner() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.berechnenButton);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("abc");
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I added the onclick here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
    Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.berechnenButton);


    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("abc");
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `return view;` instead of doing `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);` because otherwise you're just abandoning what you've done before in the code.

Comment: oh thank you, a easy solution for 3 hours searching an answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Change this from

```
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
```

to

```
  return view;
```

because you have already inflated your layout in `view` object.

Answer (score 0):

in Fragment evrey thing after return view is null if no return view is written the all code written wont work

```
enter code h super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = null;
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knastrechner, container, false);
Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.berechnenButton);


mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
});

return view;
```

}ere